# Java code only outputs the main method and skips the static one

Tags: java, methods, static

(Just started learning Java) I am trying to make a quiz but it is not outputting the information I want, it skips the "ask" method and only outputs the main method. I have to keep it as public static string.

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz {

```
public static String ask(String question) { 
 question= "What is the biggest animal in the world?\n";

    String optionA = "Blue Whale\n"; //( Correct answer)
    String optionB = "Elephant\n"; 
    String optionC = "Giraffe\n";
    String optionD = "Lion\n";
    String optionE = "Rhino\n";

    // Question string
    question += "A. " + optionA;
    question += "B. " + optionB;
    question += "C. " + optionC;
    question += "D. " + optionD;
    question += "E. " + optionE;
    
    
    while(true) {
    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
    answer = answer.toUpperCase();
    
        // Correct answer // Return Correct answer
        if(answer.equals("A")) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");return("A");} 
        
        // Incorrect answer
        else if (answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("C")|| answer.equals("D") || answer.equals("E")){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Pleae try again");}
        
        // Invalid answer
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");}}

    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {JOptionPane.showInputDialog("TEST");
}
```

}

Output : Test

Comment: ``public static void main(String[] args)`` is the entry point to the class. If you want other code executed, you need to call the other code from main().

Comment: What a strange question, did you write that code?

Comment: It's not 'skipping' the `ask` method, your code never calls it.  Replace your test dialog in `main` to `... { ask(); }`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want "ask" method to be launched. Try to place method call in the main method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           JOptionPane.showInputDialog("TEST");
           ask("");
    }
```

Comment: I got it to work with your help, thank you.